# Connection Timeout when trying to get all users

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, asp.net-membership

I am trying to get all users in a database with approximately 200k data store. I am trying to convert their passwords but I encounter a timeout while retrieving the users using .GetAllUsers(). Below is the code.

```
var encrypted = Membership.Providers["EncryptedProvider"];
        var hashedProvider = Membership.Providers["HashedProvider"];
        int dontCare = 0;
        if (encrypted == null || hashedProvider == null)
            return;
        var passwords = encrypted
            .GetAllUsers(0, int.MaxValue, out dontCare)
            .Cast<MembershipUser>()
            .Where(u => u.IsLockedOut == false && u.IsApproved == true)
            .OrderByDescending(u => u.CreationDate)
            .GroupBy(x => x.UserName)
            .ToDictionary(u => u.Key, y => y.First().GetPassword());
```

It specifically point here.

```
 var passwords = encrypted
```

I tried changing the connection string connection timeout to '0' and '9000' in the web.config. But the error still persisting.

```
<add name="ConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=xxxxx;Initial Catalog=xxxx;User ID=xxx;Password=xxx; Connection Timeout=9000;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Is there something wrong with my implementation of the code in the web.config or in the var encrypted? How do I resolve this issue?

Comment: Why the GroupBy?

Comment: I am having a duplicate issue so I added a groupby.

Comment: Are you sure it is **Connection** TimeOut? If so, then you haven't got to the stage of actually executing your query and hence it is nothing to do with the actual query or number of transactions, but is mostly likely, simply your connection string is wrong or your access to Sql is blocked. If it is a query timeout, then your connectionstring option won't affect that.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running your query in Server ?
If the timeout issue is persisting in SQL Server as well then why don't you remove the time-out limit in Server only.

Comment: Its working fine in sql server. I didnt take a lot of time fetching thousands of data.

Comment: Most likely the issue is with your connection string.
Why are you using connect timeout anyways? That is the timeout to create the connection, NOT a timeout for commands executed over that connection.
For that purpose, you need to set a command timeout using SqlCommand.CommandTimeout property.